# is there any similar way in meson as `cmake -LAH`?

Tags: meson-build

I am debugging my meson build. I want to see all the cached variables as we do in cmake. Is there any way to do this? currently I have to go into the meson.build and add all the `message()` calls which is very inefficient. The python tricks `vars()` does not work either, but this is no surprising since meson.build is not python.

Answer (score 2):

Run `meson configure build/` on your existing `build` directory, without any other parameters, to see the current configuration and possible values. Adapt `build` to your preferred build directory. You'll get something like this:

```
Main project options:                                                                              
                                                                                                   
  Core options        Current Value  Possible Values                                               Description
  ------------        -------------  ---------------                                               -----------
  auto_features       auto           [enabled, disabled, auto]                                     Override value of all 'auto' features
  backend             ninja          [ninja, vs, vs2010, vs2015, vs2017, vs2019, xcode]            Backend to use
  buildtype           plain          [plain, debug, debugoptimized, release, minsize, custom]      Build type to use
  debug               false          [true, false]                                                 Debug
  default_library     shared         [shared, static, both]                                        Default library type
  install_umask       0022           [preserve, 0000-0777]                                         Default umask to apply on permissions of installed files
  layout              mirror         [mirror, flat]                                                Build directory layout
  optimization        0              [0, g, 1, 2, 3, s]                                            Optimization level
  strip               false          [true, false]                                                 Strip targets on install
  unity               off            [on, off, subprojects]                                        Unity build
  unity_size          4              >=2                                                           Unity block size
  warning_level       3              [0, 1, 2, 3]                                                  Compiler warning level to use
  werror              true           [true, false]                                                 Treat warnings as errors
  wrap_mode           default        [default, nofallback, nodownload, forcefallback]              Wrap mode
  cmake_prefix_path   []                                                                           List of additional prefixes for cmake to search
  pkg_config_path     []                                                                           List of additional paths for pkg-config to search
                                                                                                   
  Backend options     Current Value  Possible Values                                               Description
  ...
```

and at the end of that list, the options defined in your `meson_options.txt`:

```
 ...
 Project options     Current Value  Possible Values                                               Description
  ---------------     -------------  ---------------                                               -----------
  docs                true           [true, false]                                                 Build documentation
  tests               true           [true, false]                                                 Build and run unit tests
  tools               true           [true, false]                                                 Build conversion tools
```

Answer (score 0):

Before building I always check `meson_options.txt` for possible options.

I noticed there is a file `meson-info/intro-buildoptions.json` under the build 
directory after configuring with meson.

The options from `meson_options.txt` reappear in `meson-info/intro-buildoptions.json` with their configured values.

Since that file is in json format you will need to make it more readable if needed. This is a quick and dirty way that seems to work:

```
sed -e 's/},/&\n/g' meson-info/intro-buildoptions.json|sed -ne 's/^.*{"name": "\([^"]*\)", "value": \(\[[^]]*\]\|"[^"]*"\|[^,]*\).*$/\1 = \2/p'
```

Comment: This is not what I want. intro-buildoptions.json only records all option variables. It does not record the internal variable in meson.build, which is far away from what I want to see.